# How to set Value into Slider range from code behind asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, slider

I have code like this :

```
<input type="text" id="amount" runat="server" name="amount" class="adv-search-amount"  style="width:850px"/>

<div id="slider-range" class="rangeslider"></div>


<script type="text/javascript" >
    $("#Button_Filter").click(function () {
        var min = $("#slider-range").slider("option", "values")[0].toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
        var max = $("#slider-range").slider("option", "values")[1].toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
        document.getElementById('TBRangeHargaMin').value = min
        document.getElementById('TBRangeHargaMax').value = max
    });
</script>
```

i want set value into slider range from code behind.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your HTML element has the `runat="server"` property, you can set any value or property in your code behind:

```
// Option 1
amount.Attributes.Add("Value", "20");

// Option 2
amount.Value = "20";
```

Same goes to your other elements:

```
TBRangeHargaMin.Attributes.Add("Value", "20");
TBRangeHargaMin.Value = "20";
```